# regex: get everything that doesn't fit in hooks

Tags: regex, openrefine

i try to get everything that doesn't fit in hooks with regex in OpenRefine but i'm stuck.

i have done this :

```
/^([a-z]+)\[[a-z]+\]([a-z]+)/
```

but I can't "repeat" my rule so that it applies in all these cases.

here are my test character strings :

```bash
abcd[zz]efgh[zz]ijkl[zz] 
# i want: abcd efgh ijkl

abcd[zz]efgh[zz]ijkl
# i want: abcd efgh ijkl

abcd[zz]efgh
# i want: abcd efgh

abcd[zz]
# i want: abcd

[zz]abcd
# i want: abcd
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can just split with `\[[^\]\[]*]` and filter out empty items.

Comment: I can't use it in code, so i can't use split function

Comment: We can't help without seeing your code. In code, you CAN use a split function.

Comment: As I said, I can't use code, I have to use this regex on a software called Openrefine

Comment: Try `(?=([^\]\[]+))\1(?![\]])` or `(?=([^\]\[]+))\1(?![\]\[]*])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract strings that do not contain `]` and `[` that are not immediately followed with any chars other than square brackets and then a `]` char:

```
(?=([^\]\[]+))\1(?![\]\[]*])
```

The trick is also to use an atomic first pattern so as to stop backtracking to return a part of a match. In JavaScript regex, the atomic pattern can be defined with a positive lookahead capturing a pattern, and then using a backreference to the matched text right after.

*Details*:

- `(?=([^\]\[]+))` - a positive lookahead that captures into Group 1 one or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\1` - the backreference to Group 1 that consumes the text captured into Group 1
- `(?![\]\[]*])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right, there are zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`.